# Implementing an assignment operator for a row class in a matrix library which uses expression templates

Tags: c++, c++17, type-traits, expression-templates

Suppose we have a `matrix` class which makes use of *expression templates* such that proxy objects are used to make it possible for the compiler to optimize compound expressions.

Now, it's quite natural to create a `row` class of the following form:

```
namespace detail
{
    template<class E>
    class row
        : public vector_expression<row<E>>
    {
    public:
        using size_type = size_type_t<E>;

        template<class F>
        row(F&& e, size_type i)
            : m_e(std::forward<F>(e)),
              m_i(i)
        {}

        result_of_call_operator_t<E&> operator()(size_type j) { return m_e(m_i, j); }
        result_of_call_operator_t<E const&> operator()(size_type j) const { return m_e(m_i, j); }

    private:
        E m_e;
        size_type const m_i;
    };
}
```

and a corresponding helper function of the following form:

```
template<class E, class =
    std::enable_if_t<detail::is_matrix_expression_v<E>>>
detail::row<E> row(E&& e, detail::size_type_t<E> i) {
    return { std::forward<E>(e), i };
}
```

The idea is that a `row` might be the row of an actual `matrix` object or a (temporal) `matrix_expression`.

> What I want to do now is equipping `row` with an assignment operator such that we can assign (compatible) `vector_expression`s to a `row`. Of course, such an operator should be disabled, if the related `matrix_expression` of the `row` object is not "assignable".

Here's a first idea for a useful type trait:

```
template<class E, class F>
using is_assignable_t = decltype(std::declval<result_of_call_operator_t<E>>() = std::declval<result_of_call_operator_t<F>>());
template<class E, class F>
constexpr bool is_assignable_v = is_detected_v<is_assignable_t, E, F>;
```

> Now, the problem is that we might have a `column` class and many similar classes too. So, I'm searching for a way to implement the idea described above in a way which doesn't forces me to add an assignment operator to each of these classes.

To be precise, I could equip `row` with the following operaotr:

```
template<class F,
    class = std::enable_if_t<is_assignable_v<E&, F>>>
row& operator=(vector_expression<F> const& e)
{
    /* ... */
    return *this;
}
```

However, I would need to add such an operator to the `column` class and any other class of this kind too.

> To summarize, I would like to implement this at the `vector_expression` level such that a "compatible" (i.e. elements are convertible) `vector_expression` can be assigned to a "assignable" (in the above sense) `vector_expression`. How can we do that?

I've hided the implementation details above, but [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=375e58b4bf5b0272) is a Live demo of the stuff you need to answer my question.

Answer (score -1):

In member class `numeric::detail::row`, already defined element(`m_e`) and index(`m_i`), then my code like this :

```
        template<class F,
            class = std::enable_if_t<is_assignable_v<E&, F>>>
            row& operator=(vector_expression<F> const& e)
        {
            for (size_type i = 0; i < m_e.row_size(); ++i)
            {
                m_e(m_i, i) = e(i);
            }
            return *this;
        }
```